# ASP.Net Core request and response backing stores

Tags: asp.net-core

What is the backing store of ASP.Net Core request and response body streams?

Is request stream always in memory, or ASP.Net Core stores large requests on disk? If yes, from what size, and in what folder?

Same question about response stream. Also how can I flush response to the wire? HttpResponse.Body.Flush() flushes the stream to the backing store, but does it mean it will actually be sent to the wire?

Comment: In my understanding both are "living" as an object (memory). https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/DefaultHttpContext.cs

Comment: Nether are buffered by default, the data come from and goes to the network, you shouldn't even need to call flush. You can opt into buffering either direction. Basic buffering happens in memory. Larger buffers can be written to disk in a temp file.

Comment: @Tratcher HttpResponse has an extension method `.Clear()` that I can use in the middleware to override whatever's been written to the response so far. If Response was going to the wire straight away, without buffering, this would not be possible.

Comment: I know, I wrote Clear. https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blame/87cd79d6fc54bb4abf07c1e380cd7a9498a78612/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/ResponseExtensions.cs#L11-L26 It resets the headers and status code (if the response has not started). It can only reset/Seek on the body if it has been buffered which does not happen by default.

Comment: Thanks @Tratcher, this works as you described. I thought I had tested this before and was able to clear the response in the middleware, but I tested it again - I cannot. I have now written my own response buffering, but is there anything built-in, like `EnableRewind()` for requests? I was not able to find anything.

Comment: Only a prototype https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/7803ed6e098a25fa914764dc017d0d1484cf7495/samples/ResponseBufferingSample/Startup.cs#L17